# Importing a class from another subfolder

Tags: python, import

I'm working on a project which is stored locally inside a folder called `NeuralNetwork`.

I have a .py file inside a folder `load_data` named `load_data.py`. Inside that .py file is a class names `LoadData`. I would like to import that class inside a file `test_load_data.py` stored in `NeuralNetwork/tests/test_load_data/unit_tests/test_load_data.py`

I tried to do it in the following way

```
from NeuralNetwork.load_data.load_data import LoadData
```

Unfortunately it didn't work. That's how my project looks like

```
david@macbook-air-david Lab2 % ls -1R
NeuralNetwork

./NeuralNetwork:
Datasets
__init__.py
load_data
tests

./NeuralNetwork/Datasets:
__init__.py
mnist.pkl

./NeuralNetwork/load_data:
__init__.py
load_data.py

./NeuralNetwork/tests:
__init__.py
test_load_data
test_neural_network

./NeuralNetwork/tests/test_load_data:
__init__.py
functional_tests
unit_tests

./NeuralNetwork/tests/test_load_data/functional_tests:

./NeuralNetwork/tests/test_load_data/unit_tests:
__init__.py
test_load_data.py

./NeuralNetwork/tests/test_neural_network:
```

What am I doing wrong? I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Hendrra, did my answer below solve your problem? If so, please kindly mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to `load_data.py` to add its directory to search paths:

```
sys.path.append(".") # "." refers to current working directory
```

Then `import` desired class `from` file from within `test_load_data.py`:

```
from load_data import Class
```